# Why does feast snowflake offline store only have one db and schema?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, feast

Why does feast [snowflake offline store](https://docs.feast.dev/reference/offline-stores/snowflake#example) specify a snowflake db and schema AND [SnowflakeSource](https://docs.feast.dev/reference/data-sources/snowflake) specifies a snowflake db and schema.

Can I have features in my offline store with a SnowflakeSource pointing to a different DB/schema?

Is the DB/Schema specified in the offline store config best thought of as a default that can be overridden by specifying DB/Schema in the SnowflakeSource?

Comment: I'm pretty sure what's in the documentation are example connection details - you can connect to any DB/schema/table that you want to

Comment: I'm sure it's possible to connect to any DB/schema/table with the right creds. I'm asking whether Features in the offline store can be in multiple DBs/Schemas. Not just the one specified in the SnowflakeOfflineStore: https://rtd.feast.dev/en/latest/_modules/feast/infra/offline_stores/snowflake.html#SnowflakeOfflineStoreConfig